Not able to boot into Linux or Windows 10 after install
I recently installed Linux mint on unetbootin and everything was working and then my power went out I have all the settings to dual boot but after that it gave me this message
I have secure boot disabled and it say when I load into windows boot manager that it is repairing and then does nothing help please

Welcome to Superuser. Please use punctuation in your post to help make it as clear as you can. Next, please give us more specifics about how your computer was configured, what happened when things stopped working, and what you have tried. List specific details as much as possible, including specific steps you've done.

Seems that booting entry was corrupted. Please follow these steps:

Create a Windows USB install media. You will need another computer.
Boot from USB. you may need to change BIOS settings to set USB first.
In "Install WIndows" screen, select "Repair my computer".
I don't remeber which section, but there is an "Advanced -> command prompt" option. Enter it. it will show as "X:".
Use https://g.co/gemini/share/a3ab73cad8cc to do a repair.

After that reboot system, remove USB, and see if it works.
